# Is this possible with Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, c#-4.0

Suppose you have a SQL Server database (TestDB) containing only two tables than can be created by executing the following Transact-SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Person(
   personId INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
   name VARCHAR(50)
)

CREATE TABLE House(
   personId INT,
   houseId INT,
   builtDate DATETIME,
   PRIMARY KEY(personId, houseId)
)
```

Ideally, the field **personId** in the table **House** would be a foreign key referencing the field **personId** in the table **Person**, but as you can see, **it is not**. Moreover, assume the database schema **CANNOT** be modified.

I would like to have the following classes to represent those tables by using Entity Framework

```
[Table("Person")]
public class Person
{
   [Column("personId")]
   public int Id{ get; set; }

   [Column("name")]
   public string Name{ get; set; }

   public List<House> Houses{ get; set; }
}

[Table("House")]
public class House
{
   [Column("personId")]
   public int OwnerId { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("OwnerId")] 
   public Person Owner { get; set; }

   [Column("houseId")]
   public int HouseId{ get; set; }

   [Column("builtDate")]
   public DateTime BuiltDate{ get; set; }
}

public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Person> Persons {get; set;}

   public DbSet<House> Houses {get; set;}
}
```

I think this would be the model of classes that Entity Framework would generate if there were a relationship in the database between Person(personId) and House(personId), but remember there is no foreign key constrain in the database.

I think the key question is: **How would you simulate having a foreign key when you actually don't have it?**

Remember I cannot touch the database.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you take a local copy of the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this before:

1) Take a copy of the database

2) Create the relevant foreign keys

3) Create the entity framework model from your copy

4) Change the connection string to point back to the 'live' database.

A good alternative would be to use [reverse engineer code first](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/01/30/ef-power-tools-beta-3-available.aspx) to create a code first version of your database.  Then you could add the relationships manually in code.

Comment: Is there any other approach? Maybe I won't be able to get the database to run locally.

Comment: Could you please post some code on how to create this relationships manually?

Comment: Google for Entity Framework Code First.  Start here http://codefirst.codeplex.com/